# Different http requests in the same container according to routes reactively [RXJS]

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, reactive-programming

I have a container that has two presentational components inside.

main component

```
<div>
  <app-search></app-search>
  <app-table></app-table>
</div>
```

The `app-search` component has a simple form where you choose a `year`, `month` and click `search`

The info goes up with an `@Output()`, there is an http request in the main container, and info goes down to `app-table` through `@Input`s.

Then, there is a navbar with about 10 different routes. On each route the user requests to see information about different places but all of the results fit in the same `<app-table>` component.

What I want to do, is to take the last string of the `url` and choose between different `http` requests (in a .service.ts file). Each `http` requests has this shape.

```
getSomething(cod: number, year: number, month: number) {
  const url = `123.123.123/ta&${cod}:${year}:${month}
  return this.http.get<SomeType>(url)
}
```

I thought about a long `if/else` but I wanted to think reactive. Unfortunately, I didn't succeed in it.

In summary. I want to make different `http` calls according to the last string in the `url`. How could I make a stream and orchestrate this?

My thought process about this is the following:
1. In my `auth.service.ts` make a getter of the `cod` (kept in sessionStorage)
2. Set a `BehaviorSubject` in my `main.service.ts` that stores the last string of the current url.
3. Set `BehaviorSubject`s for: `year`, `month`, and `lastUrlString`
4. Set methods to change `BehaviorSubject`'s value with `.next`. One for each
5. In the container when the user changes `year` or `month` and clicks in `search` call the `subject.next(value)` method and change year and month.

After this. I've done many things with observables, subscriptions, unsubscribings, etc. I get different errors, all the time.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by.

#### Months and year observables

Every abstract control in a reactive form has a `valueChanges` observable to which I can subscribe. So I linked those changes + and event emitter to the parent comp on every `search` button click.

```
this.searchBarForm.valueChanges.subscribe(res => {
       (this.mes = res.mes), (this.ano = res.ano);
     })

 buscarTrigger() {
     this.mes$ = of(this.mes);
     this.ano$ = of(this.ano);
     const fecha$: MesAno = { mes$: this.mes$, ano$: this.ano$ };
     this.onBuscar.emit(fecha$);
      this.onBuscar.emit({mes: this.mes, ano: this.ano})
   }
```

#### http request observable

As @observingstream mentioned in the `ngOnInit` I made a subscription to the route params. I assigned the result of it, to an observable variable.

```
this.table$ = combineLatest<Observable<DatoListaAmarilla[]>>(
        this.ruta$,
        data.ano$,
        data.mes$
      ).pipe(
        switchMap(([url, ano, mes]) =>
          this.tarjetaAmarillaService
            .getItems(url, ano, mes)
            .pipe(tap(console.log))
        )
      );
```

The rest was piping it in the template with `| async`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I completely understand what your question is, but here is an answer based on the what I think you are wanting to do. You should be using the activated route to either get the current param if your url looks like this `/url/:param` or get the current query if your url looks like this `/url?param=value`.

When you are looking to provide information to your service, you would use the ActivatedRoute to create an observable that will make an api call whenever you navigate using the navbar.

```js
export class SomeService {
  tableInfo$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    filter(paramMap => !!paramMap.get("param"))
    switchMap(paramMap => this.http.get('/api/' + param.get("param"))
  );

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

You can the subscribe to this observable in either your template using the AsyncPipe or by just subscribing in your ngOnInit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I tried a similar approach to solve it.